# Setting sampling frequency in JavaScript's navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, audio, audio-recording, web-mediarecorder

I am currently trying to set the sampling frequency inside `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`. Here is a code snippet:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: {"sampleRate": {"exact": 8000}}, video: false}).then(handleSuccess).catch(e => console.log(e));

var handleSuccess = function(stream)
{
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.start(1000); // the argument here is the duration of each audio chunk in milliseconds
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener
    ("dataavailable", event => 
        {
            blob = event.data;
            console.log(blob)
        }
    );
}
```

I don't believe setting `sampleRate` in `getUserMedia` is actually working because when I check the blob size with different `sampleRate` values, it never changes. Each blob is always within the range of 6000 to 7000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. The `sampleRate` constraint is not supported on Firefox as of October 6th, 2018. It is supposed to be supported on Chrome, but it is not functional, and I have filed a bug report in for Chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=889851

If you need to check it out for yourself, Mozilla has done a very good demo for supported media constraints: https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API/Constraints$samples/Example_Constraint_exerciser?revision=1411870

You will see at the top the supported audio constraints. If you enter the link on Firefox, you will see that `sampleRate` isn't listed there. On Chrome, it is listed, but if you enter `{"sampleRate": 8000}` inside the "Requested audio constraints" entry box and click on "Apply Constraints", you should see in the "Actual audio settings" box that the sample rate isn't affected.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you manage to change the sample rate by any other mechanism?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm going to use the next best option--downsampling to the needed sampling rate.